# How can I use the odeint function from torchdiffeq to classify two concentric annuli?

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, odeint

I have a dataset where the two classes are distributed on two concentric circles with 0 overlap. How can I use a neural ODE to solve this?

I get the error `RuntimeError: shape '[1024, 2]' is invalid for input of size 1024` when I run the network below.

```
class ODEFunc(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ODEFunc, self).__init__()

        hdim = 32
        # define your self.net as an MLP
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, hdim),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(hdim, hdim),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(hdim, 1)
        )

    def forward(self, t, y):
        return self.net(y)

class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, odefunc, device="cpu"):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.odefunc = odefunc
        # this is to make a prediction
        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, y):
        t_span = torch.linspace(0., 1., 2)
        # call odeint with your odefunc, initial value, and t_span
        pred_y = odeint(self.odefunc, y, t_span)
        # transform your output for the binary classification
        yhat = self.linear_layer(pred_y)
        return yhat
```

PS: The size of the training data is `[1024, 2]`.
PPS: 100% accuracy is not important.

Answer (score 0):

the output of odeint() is in size [1024,1], but your last linear's input is in size [1024,2]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).